# I have only one remote server environment --- how to automatically connect to it with FileZilla?

Tags: sftp, filezilla

I use FileZilla 3.46.3 to connect to my only remote server environment.

Because I have only one server enviornment, I became frustrated from FileZilla (justly and righteously) requiring me to log (to click "Quickconnect") in each time a new; although I already saved authentication details.

I need a way to not only save the details of my server environment but to log in to it directly, each time I open FileZilla (after the program is bootstrapped).

I went through FileZilla settings and under "Connection", "FTP" and "SFTP" but didn't recognize a relevant *tab*.

How to automatically connect to a single server environment with FileZilla?

### While writing this question I:

Googled that question's title and found this helpful discussion (hence the answer):
https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=50337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the article I found while writing this question](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=50337) I recognized the advice to do the following as helpful for someone in a similar situation:

> Edit → settings → Interface
>   and there check *Restore tabs and reconnect*
>   and then click "OK".

I then closed FileZilla, and then opened it → the program automatically connected to my sole server environment.

I am not sure it's the perfect solution but as of the moment it seems good enough for me personally.